# Inserting entries on new sheet based on a data sheet

Tags: excel, vba

From our drawing program we receive a sheet with data for sawing sheet material. We want to make a sticker for each unique plate.

The idea is, rearrange the data into a sticker format on a new sheet.

jpeg image for example.
[image: Example]

```vb
Sub Platen_stickers()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim xLast As Long
Dim rw As Range
Dim aantalrng As Range
Dim aantal As Range
Dim plaattype As Range
Dim Merk As String, Label As String, Lengte As String, Breedte As String
Dim stickeraantal As Byte, stickergemaakt As Byte
Dim sticker As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim x As Long

On Error Resume Next
xLast = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row 'searching last filled cell in column B

For i = 8 To xLast Step 1
    If Sheets(1).Cells(i, "B").Value2 = "Code" Then 'searching for header "Code" in column B
        Set plaattype = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, "B") 'defining the cell below "Code" as range "plaattype"
        Set aantal = plaattype.Offset(0, 2) 'defining cell in row below "Code" and in column D as range "aantal"
        Set aantalrng = Range(aantal, aantal.End(xlDown)) 'defining all numbers in column D under this header as range "aantalrng"

        'inserting new sheet for stickers after current last sheet
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = plaattype.Value2 'editing sheet name to current type
    
        Set sticker = ActiveSheet.Range(1, 1) 'defining cell A1 of current sheet as current sticker
    
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F31") 'adjusting cell dimensions of range A1:F32 to sticker format (96 sticker per sheet)
            .Columns("A:F").ColumnWidth = 18.14
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With
        For Each rw In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F32").Rows
            If rw.row Mod 2 = 0 Then
                rw.RowHeight = 5.25
            Else: rw.RowHeight = 53.25
            End If
        Next rw
        With ActiveSheet.PageSetup 'adjusting print settings to fit stickersheet
            .CenterHorizontally = True
            .CenterVertically = True
            .LeftMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .RightMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0)
            .TopMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.6)
            .BottomMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(0.6)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.3)
            .FooterMargin = Application.CentimetersToPoints(1.3)
            .Zoom = 87
        End With
    
        x = 1 'setting sticker count on 1
    
        'creating the actual sticker
        For Each row In aantalrng 'running through current data for creating stickers
            stickergemaakt = 0 'resetting counter made sticker in this row
            stickeraantal = aantalrng.Cells(row, 1).Value 'checking how many stickers this row needs making (=value of column D)
            Do Until stickergemaakt > stickeraantal 'looping until made stickers is needed stickers
                Merk = aantalrng.Cells(row, 1).Offset(0, -1).Value 'collecting sticker input
                Label = aantalrng.Cells(row, 1).Offset(0, -3).Value
                Lengte = aantalrng.Cells(row, 1).Offset(0, 1).Value
                Breedte = aantalrng.Cells(row, 1).Offset(0, 2).Value
                sticker.Value = Merk & "  " & Label & vbCrLf & Lengte & " x " & Breedte & " mm" & vbCrLf & plaattype 'writing sticker input in format on current cell on sticker sheet
                If x < 6 Then
                    Set sticker = sticker.Offset(0, 1) 'adjusting to new empty sticker cell => next column
                    x = x + 1
                ElseIf x = 6 Then
                    sticker = sticker.Offset(1, -6) 'until reached 6 columns, then next row to start again
                    x = 1
                End If
               stickergemaakt = stickergemaakt + 1 'adding counter made sticker with 1
            Loop
            stickeraantal = 0 'resetting number of stickers needed to zero for next row
        Next row
    
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The first part, inserting extra sheets and adjusting to the sticker sizes, works in my sample file.

The second part, filling the stickers with the data, I can't get started.
I suspect I'm doing something wrong with declaring the range per header.
But whatever I adjust in it, the second part doesn't work and sometimes the first part doesn't either.

Comment: If you remove `On Error Resume Next` do you get any errors?

Comment: yes, it errors on `Set sticker = ActiveSheet.Range(1, 1)`

Comment: Change `.Range` to `.Cells` you're using the wrong syntax for range. `Range("A1")` or `Range(Cells(1,1),cells(1,1))` will also work.

Comment: changed it in `"A1"` and the first row is now filled, it wont go to the next row.     _(I've read the error-line somewhere on a forum and thought i was smart by adding it in the beginning when i started whit this code)_  It errors here now `sticker = sticker.Offset(2, -6)`

Comment: From `For Each row In aantalrng` the value `row` contains is a range object, you can't put that into the arguments of a `Cells` call, should be getting a type mismatch error I'd think.

Comment: If `sticker` is in columns 1-6 (it will be A1 if it never hits the `If` and goes to `Else`) then you can't offset by -6 columns because there are no column indices <1.

Comment: @Warcupine, the " -6"  error i fixed to -5, still it doesn't go to the next row.    and now it starts running with filling the data it indeed stops on a type mismatch error on this part `stickeraantal = aantalrng.Cells(row, 1).Value` any idea how to get the current row of the looping then?

Comment: `row.row` you may want to change that variable name.

Comment: changed the `row` variable to `crw`  Now it is: `Dim crw As Range` `For Each crw In aantalrng` `stickeraantal = aantalrng.Cells(crw.row, 1).Value` Still error type mismatch on the last line

Comment: is the value it is failing on numerical?

Comment: yes, the value its looking for is the number of stickers for this row it should make and should always be numerical

Comment: Should be, but is it in actuality? What is the value of `crw.row`? As an aside on that line taking a range of a range will make it relative to the parent range, something you probably don't want.